# bash: How to properly get basename into a string?

Tags: bash

Here's my snippet:

```
__VERSION="0.0.1"
__COMMAND="${basename}"
__USAGE="$__COMMAND -abc args"
if [ $# == 0 ] ; then
    echo "Usage: ${__USAGE}"
    exit 1;
fi
```

Every time I run it I get:

> Usage:  -abc args

When I'm expecting the output to be:

> Usage: filename -abc args

I've tried:

__COMMAND=basename

__COMMAND=basename $0

__COMMAND="$basename"

__COMMAND="${basename}"

__COMMAND="${basename $0}"

Though the error has been different in some cases, none of them have worked.

What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct one is about the only one you didn't try:

```
__COMMAND=$(basename $0)
```

But you don't need `basename` at all.  You can just use bash parameter expansion:

```bsh
__COMMAND=${0##*/}
```

Comment: Thank you :D
What is the difference between $(...) and ${...} then?
I thought ${...} basically just counted as "the output of ..."

Comment: Did you check the manual?  `${...}` just does variable replacement.  `$(...)` runs a command and substitutes its output.